# Javascript combining different functions into one

Tags: javascript, html, function, methods, coding-style

let's say I have a bunch of functions like

```js
_computeValue(value1, value2) {
  //return some stuff
}

_computeIcon(value1, value3) {
  //return some stuff
}

_computeStyle(value2, value5, value1) {
  //return some stuff
}
```

What I want is to combine all this functions into a single one like this:

```js
_compute(key, parameters){
  if(key === 'style') {
    //return style function
  }
  if(key === 'Icon') {
    //return Icon function
  }
  .....
}
```

What would be the best way to do it, considering I pass different value and need to use it in the right place..

Comment: What's wrong with `if(key === 'style')`, etc? If your code works, you should post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not on StackOverflow.

Comment: Instead of having three different functions you want one function that returns three different functions?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your second code block, a `switch` statement would likely be a good solution. Example:

```js
_compute(key, parameters) {

  switch(key) {
    case 'style':
      // style code
      break;

    case 'icon':
      // icon code
      break;

    ...

    default: // optional
      // none of the above
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the functions to an object and then call them using the key:

```js
const _compute = {
  style: function fn(...params) {
    return `style: ${params}`;
  },
  icon: function (...params) {
    return `icon ${params}`;
  }
};

console.log(_compute.style(1));
console.log(_compute.icon(1,2,3));
```